# VB.NET: Adding an array of string to an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
Module globalVariable

    Public tblScItem As New DataTable
    Public tempArray()
    Public index As Integer
    Public stringArr() As String

End Module

Private Sub txtQty_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtQty.TextChanged

    stringArr = New String() {"", txtItem.Text, Form2.cbGondola.SelectedItem, txtQty.Text, DateTime.Now, Form1.txtLoginId.Text}

    If txtItem.Text <> Nothing And txtQty.Text <> Nothing Then

        index = 0

        tempArray(index) = stringArr

        tblScItem.Rows.Add(tempArray)

        index += 1

    End If

End Sub
```

My program is a stock take program which works in a way that when the quantity of the item is entered, it will display in a datagrid and at the same time, store in an array. After the entire transaction is done, the entire array is exported to a txt file.

I have declared an array `stringArr` to store all the details of the an item. Then, i used a tempArray to store each item (which contains all the details in `stringArr` in the individual index of the `tempArray`.

```
Example: 
tempArray(0) = 'details of item 1 obtained from stringArr
tempArray(1) = 'details of item 2 obtained from stringArr
and so on
```

However, i kept getting 'object is not set to an instance of an object' after the quantity is entered.

Anyone know why? I'm in need of help.

Thank you.

Comment: [Visual Studio Debugging Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: In the code you provided your tempArray has not been initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error message because you haven't initialised the `tempArray` variable. It's just a reference to an array, but it doesn't have an array to reference.

However, you are trying to put an array in an array, but the [`DataRowCollection.Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) takes an array, not an array of arrays.

Just use the `stringArr` variable:

```
Private Sub txtQty_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtQty.TextChanged

  stringArr = New String() {"", txtItem.Text, Form2.cbGondola.SelectedItem, txtQty.Text, DateTime.Now, Form1.txtLoginId.Text}

  If txtItem.Text <> "" And txtQty.Text <> "" Then

    tblScItem.Rows.Add(stringArr)

  End If

End Sub
```

Note that the `Text` property of a control is never `Empty`, you should check if it is an empty string.

If you want to add the rows to a collection other than the `DataTable`, you wouldn't use an array, as it's not resizable. You would use a `List(Of String())`:

```
Public tempList As new List(Of String())

Private Sub txtQty_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtQty.TextChanged

  stringArr = New String() {"", txtItem.Text, Form2.cbGondola.SelectedItem, txtQty.Text, DateTime.Now, Form1.txtLoginId.Text}

  If txtItem.Text <> "" And txtQty.Text <> "" Then

    tempList.Add(stringArr)

    tblScItem.Rows.Add(stringArr)

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it works great! next, i would like to export it to a txt file when the export button is clicked. However, only the last record in the datagrid is exported.                                                            Private Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

        Dim exportFile As String = "C:\Users\scannedItems.txt"
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(exportFile)
        objWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(",", stringArr))
        objWriter.Close()

    End Sub

Comment: Or, Do you think it's possible to get all the rows from the datagrid instead? in the objwriter to export it to the txtfile.

Comment: @user1699905: The `stringArr` variable only contains the last row added. Get the rows from the `tempList` variable, alternatively from the `DataTable`.

Comment: Oh. How do i get the rows from the tempList? since list doesnt support datarow.

Comment: @user1699905: The `tempList` contains string arrays, just as your `tempArray` would have. You can just loop trough it and output each array as you did `stringArr`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use DataGrid and an array? Just use the datagrid and call `Rows(0).ItemArray` on the datatable.